# how i resize when mouse over using swing?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I'm trying to resize a label on `MouseEnter`, but on `MouseExit`, I want it back to the previous state. How would I do this?

I want the label to be bigger when it is moused over, but when the mouse exits, the label will back to normal size.

Can anybody explain to me how to do that?
If it's possible, I want to see the resize slowly.

This is the code:

```
    package kk
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;


import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;


public class ScrollGroup extends JPanel {

private static final int N = 8;
    private static final int NN = N * N;
    private static final int GAP = 5;
    private static final int SIZE = 100;

    public ScrollGroup() {
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(N, N, GAP, GAP));
        for (int i = 0; i < NN; i++) {
        final    JLabel label = new JLabel();
            label.setOpaque(true);
            label.setBackground(Color.getHSBColor((float) i / NN, 1, 1));
            label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(SIZE, SIZE));
            this.add(label);
            label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()  {
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){

        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

        }

    });            
        }
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("ScrollGroup");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(this);
        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(f.getContentPane());
        f.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
        layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup().addComponent(sp)));
        layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup().addComponent(sp)));
        f.pack();
        f.setSize(N * SIZE, N * SIZE);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ScrollGroup().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are going to implement the methods of an interface you should state that the class implements that interface. `public class ScrollGroup extends JPanel implements MouseListener` and then implement all the required methods. As for changing the elements once the mouse enters or exits, check some documentation.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to resize a label in MouseEntred,

Define "resize".

You are adding your JLabels to a panel using a GridLayout. All the labels are already set to the maximum size permitted by the space available to the panel, so what do you expect the resize to do?

If you want it to appear that the label is getting bigger, then maybe you can assign a `MatteBorder` to each label. You can make the MatteBorder whatever size you want and then set the color equal to the background color of the panel.

If you want to animate then then you can use a `Swing Timer`. In the mouse#ntered you start the Timer. Every time the Timer fires you change the MatteBorder to be one less pixedl until the size is zero and you stop the Timer. On mouseExited, you just restore the default Border.

See the sections from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and [How to Use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more information.